# Pyspark appcache too big

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark streaming python application.
Spark version: 2.0
Python version: 2.6 (include with HDP 2.5.3.0)
Yarn version: 2.7

When i running my spark streaming, pyspark generate a lots of appcache file and bigger.
Please help me resolve my problem

```
[tool_vhkt@server-10-60-97-144 tool_vhkt]$ cd appcache/
[tool_vhkt@server-10-60-97-144 appcache]$ ls
application_1489545964820_0084  application_1489990352017_0010
application_1489973039223_0001  application_1489990352017_0020
application_1489973039223_0005  application_1489990352017_0021
application_1489973039223_0006  application_1489990352017_0025
[tool_vhkt@server-10-60-97-144 appcache]$ cd application_1489990352017_0025
[tool_vhkt@server-10-60-97-144 application_1489990352017_0025]$ ls
blockmgr-aeca37a6-4042-45de-8b83-e258fe6e033d
container_e32_1489990352017_0025_01_000003
filecache
spark-73a7b85b-2550-4e52-a9e6-19b56776fa1a
[tool_vhkt@server-10-60-97-144 application_1489990352017_0025]$ du -sh *
212K    blockmgr-aeca37a6-4042-45de-8b83-e258fe6e033d
108K    container_e32_1489990352017_0025_01_000003
4.0K    filecache
674M    spark-73a7b85b-2550-4e52-a9e6-19b56776fa1a
[tool_vhkt@server-10-60-97-144 application_1489990352017_0025]$ pwd
/u01/tool_vhkt/hdp/yarn/nodemanager/local/usercache/tool_vhkt/appcache/application_1489990352017_0025/spark-73a7b85b-2550-4e52-a9e6-19b56776fa1a
```

In folder **spark-73a7b85b-2550-4e52-a9e6-19b56776fa1a**, there are many files with broadcast prefix, but I do not use any broadcast variable, I wonder that pyspark automatically broadcast python global variable

```
[tool_vhkt@server-10-60-97-144 spark-73a7b85b-2550-4e52-a9e6-19b56776fa1a]$ ls
broadcast1058180300009743990  broadcast4622079796728137437
broadcast1110616477794136309  broadcast4702370114294913778
broadcast1202671379043757392  broadcast4807391796004598278
broadcast1276803072744575618  broadcast4850581263753605028
broadcast1308132491109188538  broadcast4851096518475947533
broadcast1391964928309668173  broadcast4878614870671882987
broadcast1393406243673927281  broadcast4894992928978580640
broadcast1436162117465199741  broadcast4952360795904798486
broadcast1504013522196126114  broadcast4953634337166513374
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease your log level:

```
vim $SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties

log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
```

Comment: Can you show some content of spark-73a7b85b-2550-4e52-a9e6-19b56776fa1a

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question, including the content of spark folder